# Why can I call functions declared later in the same script block, but not ones declared in later script blocks?

Tags: javascript

I use this below cod and it works as expected:

```
<script>
  function_two();
  function function_two() {
    alert("The function called 'function_two' has been called.");
  }
</script>
```

But when I apply to this code below, it doesn't work as expected:

```
<script>
  function_two();
</script>

<script>
  function function_two() {
    alert("The function called 'function_two' has been called.");
  }
</script>
```

Can someone say why?

Answer (score 7):

This is because of [*function declaration hoisting*](http://jamesallardice.com/explaining-function-and-variable-hoisting-in-javascript/). `function` declarations are *hoisted* to the top of the script. In the first case, what has actually happened is this:

```
<script>
  function function_two() {
      alert("The function called 'function_two' has been called.");
  }

  function_two();
</script>
```

The `function` declaration has been *hoisted* above the `function_two()` call.

In the second case, `function_two()` is contained within a different `script` element, and the `function` declaration cannot be hoisted above it - the code in this case remains in the same order, and `function_two()` ultimately doesn't exist when it is called.

Comment: And if s/he were to check the console, the second one will pop an error

Answer (score 0):

Due to the hoisting of javascript, declarations always get shoved to the top of a scope before execution (you can't see that, js does that itself). That's why you can use the function in your first example before you declared it.

In your second example you use seperate script elements for function declaration and usage. That is not possible, since the first script element get's compiled and executed before the browser starts to compile the second one.